# How to use PrismJS in Gatsby when the html and <code> block is contained within dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, gatsby, prismjs

So I am trying to use PrismJS within Gatbsy in order to display my code blocks. I followed this tutorial in order to get setup and running, and the following is the implementation within my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { graphql, Link } from 'gatsby';
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import SEO from "../components/seo";

//import the Prism package
import Prism from "prismjs"

const PostPage = ({ data }) => {
  const { post } = data.gcms;
  useEffect(() => {
    // call the highlightAll() function to style our code blocks
    Prism.highlightAll();
  });
  return (
  <Layout>
    <SEO
        keywords={[
          `planflow`,
          `ui`,
          `ux`,
          `information architecture`,
        ]}
        title={post.title}
      />
    <section className="w-full text-gray-700 body-font">
      <div className="container flex flex-col justify-center px-5 pb-24 mx-auto">
      <h1 className="flex justify-center mb-12 text-4xl font-semibold text-center text-black">{post.title}</h1>
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center">
          <div className="h-64 overflow-hidden rounded-lg border-1 border-gray-light">
            <img alt="content" className="object-cover object-center w-full h-full" src={post.coverImage.url}></img>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-row justify-between w-full mt-4">
            <span className="flex flex-col pl-8 mt-6">
              <h3 className="text-2xl">{post.author.name}</h3>
              <h4 className="text-black-lighter">Published: {post.date}</h4>
            </span>
            <span className="pr-8 mt-6">
            { 
              post.tags.map((tag) =>
                <span key={tag} className="inline-block px-3 py-1 mb-2 mr-2 text-xs font-medium tracking-widest capitalize border-2 border-dashed rounded border-black-lighter text-blue bg-blue-indigo">{tag}</span>
              )
            }
            </span>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col mt-6 sm:flex-row">
            {/* <div>Notication Section Here.</div> */}
            {/* {Post Content} */}
            <div className="pt-4 mt-4 text-center border-t border-gray-300 sm:w-full sm:pl-8 sm:py-8 sm:border-t-0 sm:mt-0 sm:text-left">
              <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content.html }} className="mb-4 text-lg leading-loose sm:pr-8"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </Layout>
)};

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query postPageQuery($id: ID!) {
    gcms {
      post(where: { id: $id }) {
        id
        html
    }
}`
```

Within the HTML is the relevant code block, which I assume should be detected by Prism. Ultimately, Prism does not seem to detect it, and the code is not run.

Any advise here would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### include the desired language for Prism to highlight in the `class` attribute in your `code` tags

in your content html (the one you're going to parse) make sure you are setting `class` attribute in your `code` tags to specify the language used.

Do not use `className` in the html you're going to parse. `class` is an attribute in an html element `<code class='language-javascript'></code>`.
While, on the other hand, `.className` is a property that can by called on an element to get/set its class.

```js
var element = document.createElement('code');
element.className = 'language-javascript'
// element is <span class='language-javascript'></span>
```

so make sure your code snippet in the html you're going to parse looks something like this:
example for javascript:

```html
<pre>
  <code class=”language-javascript”>
    <p>some text</p>
  </code>
</pre>
```